# Зависимость приложения от типа устройства

Tags: android, java

Я пишу приложение для Android. И тестирую его только на одном девайсе (планшет). Можно, конечно, использовать эмуляторы, но они очень медленные. И их всё равно придется использовать :) Больше всего меня волнует, какие могут быть проблемы при запуске приложения на обычном телефоне с андроидом (с маленьким экраном). Например, фрагменты. Я так понимаю, на телефоне в некоторых случаях будет отображаться только конкретный фргамент. Что нужно учитывать и как избежать проблем?

Comment: используй dp вместо pixels, а про остальные проблемы, ты нам расскажешь...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно почитать новые гайды, посвященные как раз различию интерфейса между планшетом и телефоном. Вот хороший пример: [Android Training](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html), [Dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html)

Вкратце вот в чем суть:

1. Для задания размеров компонентов использовать либо match_parent, либо wrap_content. Если не получается использовать эти константы, то нужно использовать величины, независящие от размеров экрана, то бишь dp, dip и sp предпочтительно для шрифтов.
2. Предусмотреть поведение UI при смене ориентации экрана(с портретной в альбомную или обратно)
3. О фрагментах. Из последней ссылки есть картинка. Для смартфона один фрагмент содержит  активити, которая переходит на другую активити и новый экран, для планшета, один фрагмент  обновляет другой. Хорошо описано в доке по ссылке.

Вообще, тестировать приложение лучше на 4 устройствах, минимум, желательно разных производителей, хотя самое маленькое разрешение(240х320) можно исключить, как вымирающее и получим - 320х480, 800х480, 1024х600, в идеале и плотность экрана должна отличаться, чтобы покрыть все(mdpi, hdpi, ldpi, xhdpi)

И обязательный документ: [Этот](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Я догадываюсь, что у вас тяжко с английским. Все ответы на типичные вопросы есть в документации с которой нужно конечно же работать.

С Рождеством!